# Make image source work on other computers in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble getting my image source in XMAL to work. Ofcource, I could write the whole path to the image:

```
<Image Source="D:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Wpfapplication\Wpfapplication\Icons\1385049930_arrow-left-01.png"></Image>
```

But I want to use it on more than one computer ofcourse, making me try:

```
<Image Source="Icons/1385049930_arrow-left-01.png"></Image>
```

But the image does not show up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you add the image to your WPF project ?

Comment: You gotta add the image to your Project and set it as `Resource`

Comment: How is this done more than putting the image in the folder? Am I missing something?